# chmod 755 has stopped access to databases

Tags: permissions, restore

I am trying to set wordpress permissions from some blog site. My session dropped out and I reconnected but at the default path and not in the directory. I went back to the guide and ran this command:

```
find -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
```

I realized pretty quickly and stopped the command from running but I have no idea how far it set the permissions.

I have had a couple of customers call me and say that they have issues with their websites like cannot log into the backend of wordpress and some of the plugins on the websites cannot access the data they should be able to in the database.

Could this command being run stop the database being run ? The sites are up generally so I cannot see it being an MYSQLD thing.

I am running CentOS release 6.5 (Final).

Will this have broken the server or do I have other issues? Is there a way to restore permissions? I have a backup from a week ago which I could compare the two permission but this is beyond my level of skill but happy to follow any guides (Correctly) this time!

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. use tmux or screen, so when the connection drops, you just reconnect to that session.
2. opening up permissions on directories might break e.g. SSH that checks e.g. ~/.ssh/* permissions, hard to say without specifics on what is failing (check the logs for the webserver/database/system?).
3. `find /that/backup/dir -type d -ls > /root/backupdirlist; find /that/broken/dir -type d -ls > /root/currentdirlist; diff -u /root/*dirlist` to inspect the file listings for differences, possibly first using `awk` or `cut` or something to just show the filename and permissions bit, and not any of the other columns.
4. in the future, `find -type d -print0 |xargs -0 echo chmod 755` first to see what would happen, or `find -type d -print0 |xargs -0 chmod --verbose 755 | tee somelog` to log what you did.
5. invent time travel.

Comment: 6. Restore the file tree from your backup. (You have customers, so you must have backups, right?)

Comment: Hi, Yes I have a backup from the 8th of the entire shapshot. (Digital Ocean) I have nightly backups of DB's and files for my clients. I have also managed to get the websites backup by changing the permissions on the MYSQL tmp folder. 'mysqldump --all-databases > all_databases2.sql -u root -p --lock-tables=false' came up with a out and mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show fields from `wp_commentmeta`': Can't create/write to file '/home/tmp/#sql_4ad_0.MYI' (Errcode: 13) (1) So giving the correct permission to TMP and then restarting the mysqld service did the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need to restore the file tree on Monday morning just incase other services are not working as required. What is the process for this or could you give me the command so I can do some research?